# Groovy coverage not analyzed

Tags: java, maven, groovy, sonarqube

we have a multi-module-maven project where some modules are written in groovy and some in java. When we run mvn sonar:sonar the java modules are correctly analyzed but the groovy modules are not, so they are not shown in sonarqube.

we have written a simple project (https://github.com/BigMichi1/coverage) that shows this

we use sonarqube 5.2 with java plugin 3.7.1 and groovy plugin 1.3

we tried to add a `sonar-project.properties` and set the paths and language there but with no luck

what can we do to get the groovy modules analyzed?

Comment: Can you share the log of the analysis ? at least to verify that the groovy sensor is executed in expected modules ? Note also that analyzing the files (ie raising issues) is different that importing coverage reports.

Comment: i added the maven log (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BigMichi1/coverage/master/logs/maven.log) and also the background analysing log from sonar (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BigMichi1/coverage/master/logs/sonar-background.log)

Comment: From the log it seems that the groovy sensor is not executed (btw, please copy paste your log to make your question self contained, your link might not be always up). Please remove any configuration of sonar.language.

Comment: in the sample project i mentioned above there is no setting for ```sonar.language```

Comment: anything else we can try to get coverage working?